# create a variable from a class's other class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to create a variable from a .class's second class.

```
var post_id = $('.divclass').hasClass('');

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(post_id).click(function() {
        $(this).fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

I know this is wrong, but maybe someone here can help make sense of that I'm trying to do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by *a .class's second class*, can you brief that.?

Comment: div has class1 & class2. class1 is static, class2 is variable. I'm trying to use class2 as a selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you'll need to do is select the item with more than one class which you are doing:

```
var post_id = $('.divclass').attr('class');
//Now spilt the string by all of the spaces
post_id.split(" ");
//now refer to the string as an array
//lets get the second one.
post_id[1]
```

So for your case

```
//Added selector in this case a class with '.' this can be changed to be appropriate i.e '#' for an ID
$('.'+post_id[1]).click(function() {
    $(this).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! 
Now to figure out how to make this work with multiple instances of .divclass. Works like a charm for the 1st, 2nd one not so lucky!

Comment: will it always be the second class? Thats the tricky thing in this particular problem...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t2ALn/13/ here's my problem in jfiddle - it only works on the 1st instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your `post_id` is a boolean. You are trying to attach an event handler to a boolean, when you should instead be attaching it to a DOM element. Don't use has class, but instead retrieve the class attribute:

```
var post_id = $('.divclass').attr('class');
post_id = post_id.replace('divclass', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're having 2 classes like below :

```
<div id="trash" class="a b">
    <p>sample</p>
</div>
```

Then you can use jQuery selector is as below :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.a.b').click(function() {
        $(this).fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

I hope this will help to you.